# Доступ к HTTP-серверу в Docker контейнере с устройства вне локальной сети

Tags: сеть, docker, ip

Я использую такой стек: `Windows` | `VirtualBox` | `Ubuntu` | `Docker` -> `nginx`

Хочу получить доступ к `nginx` с устройства не входящего в мою домашнюю локальную сеть, то есть через внешний `ip` моего `Windows`.
Всё настроил и сейчас могу получить доступ к `nginx` с любого устройства в моей домашней сети по внутреннему `ip` моего `Windows`, но по внешнему `ip` моего `Windows` - не работает.

Где могут быть проблемы, в какую сторону смотреть? Я новичок в сетях, возможно мой вопрос глупый, не ругайтесь сильно, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: под внутренним вы подразумеваете что-то из 192.168.x.x сети? компьютер подключен напрямую к сети или через роутер/свитч и т.д.?

Comment: @Exploding Kitten да, внутренний 192.168.x.x. Компьютер подключён к роутеру. Все устройства сети образованной этим роутером имеют доступ к `nginx` по внутреннему `ip`. Но я хочу, например со смартфона получить доступ по внешнему `ip`

Comment: вам нужно настроить port forwarding на роутере, как это делать смотрите в документации или интернете, примеров должно быть много, идея в том, что вам нужно чтобы роутер "пробрасывал" трафик с некоторого порта на ваш сервер

Comment: @Exploding Kitten спасибо, попробую. Что такое припоминаю, когда искал информацию

Comment: @aleksandr barakin спасибо за ссылку